# Text box with Turkish language typing support

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

i want text-box in my website which can use to type Turkish language. I have tried to search on Google but nothing got. my website is developed in php,jquery,html & css.

Answer (score 1):

Turkish is not handled in utf-8. 
Make sure your website uses iso-8859-9 (Latin-5) by putting a php header

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-9');
```

defining meta-charset in html sometimes is not enough.

Be aware that this may cause trouble with other contents or icons on your site.

Comment: it still taking english text when i typing in text box

Comment: of course you need to have an turkish keyboard-language on your machine